# VMware Fusion and CentOS black screen

Tags: centos, vmware, virtual-machine

Just installed CentOS 5.8 on a VM using VMware Fusion 3.1.4 on my MB Mac OS X 10.7.4 and have the following problem. CentOS finished to install and re-start. The result, a nice black screen. I rebooted CentOS (on the VM) no success. I rebooted VMware Fusion, no success. I rebooted the whole machine (physical machine) no success.

Is there anywhere VMware Fusion log booting errors I can investigate why I have this annoying black screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware Fusion logs errors in the virtual machine's bundle.
So, for example, if your virtual machine appears on your hard disk on the desktop as:
myvm
you will find it in Terminal at:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ls -1 myvm*
```

... myvm.vmwarevm

then:

```
cd myvm.vmwarevm
```

you will see:
**vmware.log**
(and maybe vmware-0.log, etc, which will be older logs; vmware-0 being second most recent, vmware-1 being third most recent.)

A very late answer, but hope that is some help.